# Does magnetism play a role in the formation of galaxies?

Tags: magnetic-fields, astrophysics, dark-matter, galaxies, structure-formation

Forgive my ignorance as I know next to nothing about physics. From my layperson's understanding, galaxies are formed primarily by the interaction of gravitational forces of stars and planets, however, it offers an insufficient explanation according to physicists. They theorize adding dark matter as an additional factor to fully complete the picture.

Given the abundance of iron created by stars along with heat and motion, are magnetic fields and possibly electric current generated at the gigantic scale of galaxies? Could it also play some role in their formation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"[A new study of IC 342](https://astronomy.com/news/2015/06/magnetic-field-discovery-gives-clues-to-galaxy-formation-processes) indicates that magnetic fields play an important role in forming spiral arms. " (2015)

Comment: Interesting stuff. If that result is to be trusted, it looks like the magnetic field is anti-correlated with the luminous matter.

Answer (score 0):

Magnetic fields posses an  energy density of $\frac{1}{2\mu_0}|\vec{B}|^2$

This Energy has a generates a gravitational pull. Contributing to the formation of galaxies.

Comment: In principle, yes, but in practice, no. The gravitational field produced by magnetic fields is not an important factor in galaxy formation.

Comment: But would that be the only factor if we are to consider magnetic fields? I cannot think of any others

Comment: I don't know (this is outside my area of expertise). I could imagine that magnetic fields could be related to a galaxy's rotation (but again, I have no idea). But we can think about whether the gravitational effects of galaxy-size magnetic fields affect galaxy evolution independently of other possible effects magnetic fields might have. The gravitational force due to magnetic fields is way too small to be relevant.

Comment: The impact is utterly negligible.

Comment: The gravity of magnetic fields is negligible compared to the electromagnetic force they exert on the galactic and intergalactic plasma.